# Ruby on Rails, broken url() in css after concatenation

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bower

**Situation**

1. Use `bower` In `.bowerrc`
2. In `bowerrc` set directory `vendor/assets/bower_components`
3. In config `application.rb` I typed `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')`
4. Install gallery plugin called «fotorama», do it by bower
5. All files of plugin «fotorama» now storage in this directory `"/vendor/assets/bower_components/fotorama"`
6. In manifest css file `application.css` I type `*= require fotorama/fotorama.css`
7. In layout file I typed `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`

Starting server `rails server` — everything is ok. In source of generated page I see `<link href="/assets/fotorama/fotorama.css?body=1" rel="stylesheet" />`. This css file has this line `.fotorama__video-play {background: url(fotorama.png) no-repeat}`, and many other lines where uses url for file "fotorama.png", and it is ok, browser try to find this png file near the css file, and successfully do it.

Stop server, precompile all essets `rake assets:precompile`, and then run server in production environment `rails server -e production`

**Problem**

In production, all my css files concatenated, and in source of page it looks like this `<link href="/assets/application-2d31fc33890d01b046194920367eb3d4.css" rel="stylesheet" />`, and still this file has this line `.fotorama__video-play {background: url(fotorama.png) no-repeat}`. Now browser trying to find png file here `http://localhost:3000/assets/fotorama.png`, but it isn't here, it isn't anywhere, because, I don't know why, there is no `"fotorama.png"` in `"public/assets"` folder.

**Questions**

1. Why pictures didn't transport from `"/vendor/assets/bower_components"` to "`public/assets`"
2. Have you got an idea, what can I do to solve my problem? Important, that I don't want to change urls in css manually, programatically — ok.

*Excuse me for my english, and thanks for everybody who going to help me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution and answers**

1. Only files from `"app/assets"` transports to `"public/assets"` by default. To transport images from `"/vendor/assets"` type in `"application.rb"` this code `config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)`
2. Task for gulp: if you see some changes in `"bower.json"`, take all main files of bower components by npm moudle called "main-bower-files". Generate a manifest file with each css file with `.erb` extension, and save it `"app/assets/stylesheets/bower_components_manifest.css"`
3. This task continue: in every main css files, by npm module called "gulp-css-url-adjuster", add before every url `<%= asset_path '` plus path to directory, and after `' %>`. `url("fotorama.png")` >> `url("<%= asset_path 'fotorama/fotorama.png' %>")`. Add `.erb` extension and save.
4. In `"app/assets/stylesheets/application.css"` I add `* require bower_components_manifest`.

One of the other solutions, use gem "bower-rails". But I don't like it, because in some plugins in bower I need override some "main" files, and gem "bower-rails" can't do this, npm "main-bower-files" can. And I like to save my workflow for everything what I have done before start include my code to rails, gulp, bower.